# What does "by continuing you agree to share resources" on a website mean?

Tags: web-browser, bitcoin

I recently encountered this message on a website:

"By continuing you agree to share resources. Your browsing speed will not be affected."

When I get 'learn more', it redirected to me an obscure digital currency webpage (I forgot the name). It was something like Bitcoin. What happens when I hit 'continue'?

What exactly does 'share resources' mean? I know that Bitcoins need huge computing power to mine a coin, but the webpage I was redirected did not mention bitcoin. If it's something similar to bitcoin mining, does the webpage use my resources when I'm not on the webpage?

Comment: Since there are some `Push API` features nowadays, the idea of mining bitcoins via `Service Worker` even when user is no longer on the websites seems pretty doable?! Please confirm/reject (?) me on this, since I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes! I remember it now. It was Monero.

Answer (score 4):

It means that this website uses a Javascript cryptocurrency mining script.

The resources in question are your CPU/RAM/GPU which will be used to mine coins for the benefit of the website owner.

It's another form of website monetisation, like ads or data selling.

Comment: Can a GPU even be used for mining in browser context? WebGL is a lot more limited than OpenCL.

Comment: @forest it's probably trickier than with OpenCL but i was able to find some webgl miner in two google query, so i would say "most probably possible" (i didn't check if they were working)

Comment: So will it use my CPU/RAM/GPU even when I'm not using that particular website?